# Can I uninstall Caribou without messing up Gnome?

Tags: uninstall

I just installed the Gnome Tweak Tool in order to change my icon theme to Faenza, but it seems to have installed some other program named Caribou, which I think is an onscreen keyboard program, with it. This is absolutely useless for me, and frankly, I hate the fact that it was installed silently and without my permission. When I go to uninstall it, it says that it's part of gnome-shell and requires the un-installation of that as well. What do I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can uninstall Caribou (which provides an on-screen keyboard), or (as [JoZ3](https://askubuntu.com/users/30663/joz3) has [suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80032/uninstall-caribou/80042#80042)) you can keep it installed but prevent it from starting up automatically (i.e., "disable" it). The latter may be preferable in that you can still run the program should you find you have use for it (without reinstalling it).

**To uninstall Caribou**, you can find the package called `caribou` in the Software Center and remove it. Make sure to heed any warnings about other packages that would have to be removed along with it...though for `caribou`, this is unlikely to be a problem. If there are packages that the Software Center indicates will be removed automatically when you remove Caribou, and you're not sure whether or not going through with removing Caribou would cause problems, then please post the list of packages here. In case this puts it in a more convenient form, you should be aware that you can get this information in the Terminal by running `apt-get -s remove caribou`. (The absence of a leading `sudo` is intentional.)

**To disable Caribou** from starting up automatically when you log in, for all users, remove the entry for `caribou.desktop` in the file `/etc/xdg/autostart`. Since that file is owned by `root`, you must edit it as `root`. One way to do that is to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run the command:

`gksu gedit /etc/xdg/autostart`

(This is from [this forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1858790), found by [JoZ3](https://askubuntu.com/users/30663/joz3).)

You might want to back up the file first, before editing it, in case you make a mistake. To do that, open a Terminal window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run the command:

`sudo cp /etc/xdg/autostart /etc/xdg/autostart.old`

Comment: autostart is a directory for me.  I used:  
    cd /etc/xdg/autostart;  
    sudo gedit caribou*;  
... and changed "true" to "false" in that file.

Comment: gnome-core depends on caribou. I am not sure how useful the `uninstall caribou` solution is for people expecting to use gnome.

Answer (score 0):

You can't uninstall, but you can disable check the link [how to disable caribou in ubuntu 11.10](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1858790)

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 12.04 you can do this:

applications>system tools>preferences>applications at start

In the opening window uncheck caribou and close it. You can also uninstall it there if you want.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 18.04, the accepted answer is not applicable because `/etc/xdg/autostart` is a directory with nothing in it that sounds like `caribou`.

However, there is a gnome shell extension in the Ubuntu Store called "Block Caribou" with good reviews.