# How to disable the on screen keyboard in 17.10

Tags: keyboard, 17.10, onscreen-keyboard

Everytime I touch the screen, even in a non text entry area, this keyboard pops out.  How can I disable it?  It is very jarring

Comment: You can't,  though maybe it can be made less obvious.. welcome to gnome-shell

Comment: You can either uninstall or disable Caribou (on screen keyboard) - See https://askubuntu.com/questions/80032/can-i-uninstall-caribou-without-messing-up-gnome for both options.

Comment: Uninstalling caribou really messed up my system!

Comment: This is a known bug. Please mark yourself affected here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-desktop/+bug/1723857

It's been a problem since 2015: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1274956,https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=742246

Florian made some patches this year (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=788188), but I don't know how to apply them. Hence my as-of-yet unanswered question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/965598/how-do-i-apply-a-gnome-patch

A guy made a GNOME extension to kill Caribou: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1326/block-caribou/

Comment: Welcome to FOSS.

Comment: I am a die hard Ubuntu + GNOME user and I still feel compelled to say this bug is straight up trash that makes our whole community look foolish.

Answer (score 15):

This is a known bug. Please mark yourself affected [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-desktop/+bug/1723857).

It's been a problem since 2015: see [on redhat](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1274956), on [GNOME bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=742246), and now on [gitlab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/2991).

Florian made some [patches in 2017](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=788188), but I don't know how to apply them. Hence my as-of-yet [unanswered question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965598/how-do-i-apply-a-gnome-patch?noredirect=1#comment1545642_965598).

In the meantime, this guy made a [GNOME extension to kill Caribou](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1326/block-caribou/)

Comment: You apply them to the gnome-shell source & rebuild. Best choice for most users is to hope the patches are accepted & then you'll see in 18.04. The idea that 17.10 is for everyday use is misguided..

Comment: Would you please explain how to patch in detail on https://askubuntu.com/questions/965598/how-do-i-apply-a-gnome-patch?noredirect=1#comment1545642_965598?

Comment: Also, 17.10 is for everyday use. Your claim that it's misguided is bold. Please provide evidence to support your bold claim, or accept the consensus that 17.10 is for everyday use.

Comment: Is there some "Just do it" solution?

Comment: Does the GNOME extension to "block caribou" not qualify?

Answer (score 14):

**To switch off the keyboard**

1. Click the "Universal Access" icon in the top-right action bar.
2. Click the "Screen Keyboard" to "Off"
3. The "Universal Access" icon will disappear if no other options are "on".  **See below if you want to switch the keyboard on and off more easily and quickly!**

[image]

**To switch keyboard on when the Universal Access Bar is unavailable**

1. Go to Settings -> Universal Access
2. Set "Screen keyboard" switch to "On"

[image]

**To force the the Universal Access bar to always be available**

1. Go to Settings -> Universal Access
2. Set "Always show Universal Access Menu" switch to "On"

[image]
It's unfortunate that there's no "Only when no other keyboard is available" option yet.  Hopefully that will come soon. The Gnome version is far more tablet-friendly than Unity. :-)

Comment: @tom-mercer I wouldn't have answered it if I hadn't tested it!  Works on the version of 17.10 I installed on Friday!

Comment: Turn off the keyboard in UA. Now touch your screen- drag, change windows, scroll, etc. What happens?

Comment: Yeah, gnome3 is tablet friendly, too bad that tablets are a single digit percentage minority while all the rest of desktop users have to suffer such usability issues. As far as I am concerned because of the hardcoded primary screen "feature" Gnome3 is pretty useless on multi-screen setups, where Unity was the best availabe option.

Comment: I'm on 18.04 and sometimes the keyboard gets "stuck" on the screen. If I go into Universal Access, the setting is "off". If in turn it "on" and then "off" again, the keyboard goes away. I'd really like to nerf it permanently.